# Deleting rdf triples using statement ID in jena

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, ontology

Iam master student my project is to develop storymodel in jena. Now my task is to delete a statement using Id.  If this is a statement:

```
{member1, member2, member3,  member4, statementID}
```

For Example:

```
[Alice, saw, mouse, garden].
```

statementID is invisible to the user.

In my model the above statement is saved as `[ID, Property, Value]`:

```
[statementID, hasSubject, Alice] ; 
[statementID, hasEvent, saw] ; 
[statementID, hasBeneficiary, Mouse] ; 
[statementID, hasLocation, garden]
```

In this way there are many statements like `[bob, like, alice]`, `[Edwin, meet, mouse, garden]` and so on. In order to delete a selected statement, I have to built a method that finds all the triples for the selected statementID and delete them. My professor suggested me to use Sparql query to find the triples for selected statement ID, as its a new topic to me I have started reading about sparql query.

Comment: Please show some of the RDF data that represents a statement;  it doesn't sound too hard to identify the triples that you're trying to delete, but without an example of your data, it's hard to say exactly what the query will be.

Comment: Why is all the substance of this question suddenly edited out? Please don't vandalize the question after you've had your anwer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a concrete example of your data, it's hard to say exactly what your query will be.  Even so, it sounds like you're simply asking to delete all the triples whose subject is some particular `statementId`.  That would just be:

```
delete { <statementId> ?p ?o }
where { <statementId> ?p ?o }
```

See [3.1.3.1 DELETE (Informative)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-update-20130321/#delete) in the SPARQL 1.1 specification for more information and examples.